# Directional Derivative of a Norm of a Function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have a fixed vector $\vec v \in \mathbb R^d $ and a norm $\frac 1 2 \| F(x) - y \|^2$. How can i compute its derivative in the direction of $\vec v$? Which means I have to compute the following:

$$\partial_{\vec v } \frac 1 2 \| F(x) - y \|^2 $$

Note that $F(x): \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^k $ is a continuous and differentiable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

- $\|F(x)-y\|^2=\langle F(x)-y,F(x)-y\rangle$
- $\partial_v\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle= \langle \partial_v f(x), g(x)\rangle+ \langle f(x), \partial_v g(x)\rangle$